# Incomplete pattern matching in F# using read files and lists

Tags: f#, functional-programming

So i have this code

```
let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath);
let lines = Seq.toList (readLines "MovieSmall.txt");
let lines2 = List.map (fun (s:string) -> Array.toList (s.Split([|'\t'|]))) lines;
let imdb = List.map (fun (l1::l2::l3::l4::l5::l6::[]) -> [l1]::[l2]::[l3]:: (Array.toList ((l4:string).Split[|','|])) ::[l5]:: (Array.toList ((l6:string).Split[|','|])) ::[]) lines2;;
```

That gets data from a file called MovieSmall and parses it into a String Linked List.

MovieSmall.txt looks like this

```
The Shawshank Redemption    1994    9.30    Crime, Drama     Frank Darabont  Morgan Freeman
The Godfather   1972    9.20    Crime, Drama     Francis Ford Coppola    Al Pacino,  James Caan,  Robert Duvall,  Diane Keaton,  Talia Shire
Universal's Cinematic Spectacular: 100 Years of Movie Memories  2012    9.20    Documentary, Short   Mike Aiello     Morgan Freeman
```

I get

```
  let imdb = List.map (fun (l1::l2::l3::l4::l5::l6::[]) -> [l1]::[l2]::[l3]:: (Array.toList ((l4:string).Split[|','|])) ::[l5]:: (Array.toList ((l6:string).Split[|','|])) ::[]) lines2;;
  --------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(4,27): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '[_;_;_;_;_;_;_]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).
```

Which I'm sure is ok because all the data fed to it will have the format above, but when I run

```
let rec get_rating movie = function
    | [] -> "Not found";
    | [[title]; b; c; d; e; f]::t -> if title=movie then  (string)c else get_rating movie t;

get_rating "Batman Begins" imdb;;
```

i get

```
let rec get_rating movie = function
  ---------------------------^^^^^^^^

stdin(24,28): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '[[_;_;_;_;_;_;_]]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

val get_rating :
  movie:'a -> _arg1:'a list list list -> string when 'a : equality
val it : string = "[8.30]"
```

While adding the case of

```
let rec get_rating movie = function
    | [] -> "Not found";
    | [[title]; b; c; d; e; f]::t -> if title=movie then  (string)c else get_rating movie t;
    |_-> "Does not match";

get_rating "Batman Begins" imdb;
```

Stops it from happening I dunno if this is the correct way to approach this.
Thoughts?

Comment: The case `| _ ->` is a catch all case. Applying to any `match`  with the warning `warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression.` will always clear the warning. Since you seem confident that the first pattern will always work, then all that you have done is removed a warning. However if the data changes in the future and the pattern does not hold then the `| _ ->` will catch it instead of causing a run time error.

Comment: You don't need to have the `;` at the end of F# code lines.  Even in F# Interactive you only need to enter `;;` when you want it to execute a complete expression.

Comment: Thank you. So I will always get an incomplete pattern match or do i go through all the cases and look for possible hiccups?

Comment: @SuperCell You're actually already doing that :).  If your code sees the expected pattern it will get the movie rating if it sees any other pattern it will print `Does not match` and tell you that something's wrong with the data.

Answer (score 4):

When you only want to match on a small subset of all the possible patterns, as you're doing here, then finishing the `match` statement with `_ -> default logic` is exactly what you want to do.

The F# compiler is throwing that warning because when you leave your pattern matches incomplete you're opening your code up to run time failures when unexpected data comes through.  Added the `| _ ->` pattern at the end lets you dictate what action to take when something unexpected happens.

Long story short, you're taking the right approach by having the `_-> "Does not match"` in your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable compiler warnings:

```
#nowarn "25"
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a really bad idea